# Appending two strings without str functions

Tags: c, string, struct, append

I'm having an issue trying to figure out how to append the char pointer c to the existing Struct `String`. I want to be able to take in input as such (considering a predefined Struct with the value of stuff being "Hello") `append(test,"world")` When I try to use `strcat` and `strcpy` I get an error because the structure String is not a valid type to be used with this function.

How do I append without the use of the `str` functions?

I currently have code that declares a structure and sets stuff to be the value of the contents of the structure in this case **hello** I enter my function and check if the data the person is passing is not null.  I create a new String Struct called append and `realloc` memory to the new size of the previous "stuff" plus the value of *c.  Should I use a for loop to get the contents of *c at the point [i] into the end of append?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory.h>

typedef struct strstf {
    char  * stuff;
    size_t  length;
} String;

String * append(String * b, const char * c) {
    String * append;
    if (c != NULL) {
        /* creates memory the size of the original string buffer and the added string */
        b->stuff realloc(strlen(c) + strlen(b->stuff) + 1);
        strcpy(append, b->stuff);
        strcat(append, c);
        return append;  
    }
    if (append->stuff == NULL) {
        free(append);  
        return NULL;
    }
    return append;
}
```

Comment: You should choose different names for your `append()` function and your `append` variable.

Comment: `append = (String*) realloc(b->stuff,...` --> such as `b->stuff = realloc(b->stuff,...`

Comment: this line: 'if(!(c = NULL)){' is not correct, it is assigning NULL to c.   so the 'if' will always be true.   This is one of the (many) reasons to always place the literal on the left.  I.E. 'if(!(NULL = c)){'  Then the compiler would have raised a error message and you would not need to spend you valuable time debugging that problem.

Comment: this line: 'b->stuff realloc(strlen(c) + strlen(b->stuff) + 1);' does not compile.  it is missing a '=' after 'b->stuff'.   When asking for help with a runtime problem, please post code that cleanly compiles (that includes all needed #include statements, data definitions, etc)

Comment: when using realloc(), always save the returned value into a temp variable, then check (!=NULL) the temp variable, before assigning to the actual target variable.  Otherwise, if the realloc() fails, which it can do, then  1) the original pointer is lost, resulting in a memory leak  2) any dereference of that (now NULL) target variable will result in a seg fault event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *a lot* of things wrong with your code. Here's what I noticed just right of the bat:

1. You used a variable name `append` inside a function called `append`, which is bad form. I'm not even sure if that compiles.
2. The`=` operator was used when `==` was actually needed. The former is for
   assignment, and therefore the condition would always be true.
3. `realloc()` was used on `b->stuff`, which is a `char*`, but you cast it to a `String*`. That may technically work, but it's really bad form.
4. After you used `realloc()` on `b->stuff` you still used the pointer `b->stuff` even though `realloc()` invalidates the pointer it was passed and returns a new one.
5. `strcpy` and `strcat` on a pointer to type `struct strstf`, when they both require a `char*`

---

The following code works. You just need to remember to free both the pointer `result` *and* `result->stuff`. That's a very easy spot for a memory leak.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct strstf {
    char   *stuff;   
    size_t  length;   
} String;

String *append(String *b, const char *c){
    String* result = malloc(sizeof(String)); /* allocate memory for the resulting string */

     if (c != NULL && b != NULL && b->stuff != NULL) { /* make sure nothing is NULL */
        result->length = strlen(c) + b->length; /* calculate the length of the new string */
        result->stuff = malloc(result->length + 1); /* allocate the memory for the char array (plus '\0' char) */
        strcpy(result->stuff, b->stuff); /* copy the first to the result */
        strcat(result->stuff, c); /* append the second to the first */
        return result;  /* return the result */
    }
    return NULL; /* something went wrong */
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    String first;
    String* result;
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("The syntax of the command was incorrect.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    first.stuff = argv[1];
    first.length = strlen(argv[1]);

    result = append(&first, argv[2]);

    printf("Result: %s\n", result->stuff);

    free(result->stuff); /* DON'T FORGET THIS */
    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like the solution, but one nit. When I hit the CamelCase `String` in what looks to be clean C, it is like running into a brick wall. Ouch!  It's that bad. Suggestion, just use `strstf` instead. You can use it both for the struct_space and typedef name, or, in this case, you don't even need the initial `strstf` at all. You can simply move it to replace `String`. Just a pet peeve, quirk, call it what you will, but upper-case in C is reserved for system use... (others will obviously have different opinions...) Good answer though `:p`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If this had been my program, I most certainly would have used another name. However, I used the name `String` to follow the style of his original code. This may only be a code snippet, and he may have to do some unwanted refactoring in order to change it.

Comment: Fair enough. I just had to chime in when I hit that wall. In the grand scheme of things it doesn't really matter, but for old folk, we're kind of stuck in our ways... You might also want to help others out in the future by pointing out the style differences as well.

Comment: TO avoid unneeded walk though `result->stuff` with `strcat(result->stuff, c);`, use `strcpy(result->stuff + b->length, c);`